# rt media plugin count not working in shortcode

Tags: plugins, buddypress

I used rtMedia plugin in my buddypress site. I used the short code  `<?php echo do_shortcode('[rtmedia_gallery global="true" media_type="all" count="4" loadmore="false"]'); ?>` to dispaly media gallery items. But the count and load more not working. It shows more than 4 items now. How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of now rtMedia Gallery shortcode `rtmedia_gallery`, doesn't support `count` as it's attribute.

In order to limit the number of media, you have to change the media count from rtMedia Settings. Here is the screenshot:

[image]

You just need to set a desired value for media items in the input.

Also you can directly ask rtMedia related questions on the [support forum](http://rtcamp.com/support/forum/rtmedia/) for plugin, it's quite active.

Comment: Do you got it working?

Comment: Yes it works. If i used the short code in more than one place i need a solution to change the count of items to display.

Comment: You can request a feature at the support forum, and also mark it as answer